# Getting Php and mysql database to communicate

Tags: php, mysql, vps

I am using php to get my xcode app to read and write data to my mysql database. This is my code

```
<?php
 if (isset($_GET["userName"])  && isset($_GET["password"]) ){
            $userName = $_GET["userName"];
            $password = $_GET["password"];
            $result = login( $userName, $password);
            echo $result;
            }

function makeSqlConnection()
{
 $DB_HostName = "what do i put here?";
$DB_Name = "i know this";
$DB_User = "and this";
$DB_Pass = "And this";

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 

    mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

return $con;
}

function disconnectSqlConnection($con)
{
mysql_close($con);
}

function login($userName, $password)
{

$con = makeSqlConnection();

$sql = "select * from user  where userName = '$userName' and password = '$password';";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

$res1 = mysql_num_rows($res);

disconnectSqlConnection($con);

 if ($res1 != 0) {
    return 1;
}else{
    return 0;
}


} 

?>
```

Also what do i have to do about making it secure. Thanks for any help given. 
Also i run this off my vps.

Guys in xcode to post the data i am using this code:

```
- (IBAction)continueClicked:(id)sender {
NSInteger success = 0;
@try {

    if([[self.txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];

    } else {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"userName=%@&passWord=%@",[self.txtUsername text],[self.txtPassword text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"(my php url)"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error:&error];

            success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
            NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }

        } else {
            //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
}
if (success) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
}
}
```

Not gonna lie i did find this code eldewhere and am trying to get it to work so i can make a login page.

Comment: I think it is specifically the hostname part that is causing the problem. Do i put local host or?

Comment: The hostname depends on your actual setup. `localhost` works in many cases, give it a try. To make it more secure, DO NOT use string concatenation to build your sql queries but use prepared statements.

Comment: And mysql_* functions are deprecated, use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: [OP's debugging technique](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/50117539.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your connection:

```
function makeSqlConnection()
{
    $DB_HostName = "localhost";
    $DB_User = "your_database_user";
    $DB_Pass = "your_database_user_password";
    $DB_Name = "your_database_name";

    $con = mysql_connect( $DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass, $DB_Name ) or die( mysql_error() ); 

    return $con;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *$DB_HostName* should be your host name/Server IP address, and port.
For instance, lets say you have a server that has an IP address: *162.2.2.1* and your MySql port on that server is *3306* (default port for mysql if i am not mistaken) - you should now write $DB_HostName = *'162.2.2.1:3306'* and that's it!
If you have a host name instead, db.php-db.com you can write that instead of the IP address:
$DB_HostName = *'db.php-db.com:3306'*

Regarding security issues: You can use SSL encryption to make your connection encrypted, read more here: https://serverfault.com/questions/261134/is-mysql-port-3306-encrypted-and-if-no-how-can-i-encrypt-it

Good luck,
  Tom.